# Getting git-latexdiff and texcount to work together nicely

Tags: latexdiff, git, texcount

What is the best way to get `git-latexdiff` to work nicely with `texcount` to view changed and deleted word counts between two commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to get this working, so just in case someone else comes looking for this in the future!

The first thing I did was use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614834/31561) so that `texcount` will use the formatting of `latexdiff` to be able to count added and deleted words.

There are several problems using this with `git-latexdiff`, however. The first is that `gitlatex-diff` uses `latexpand` to flatten any files that are included with `\input` or `\include` into one large `.tex` file. By default, this also removes any comments, including those `%TC:` comments for `texcount` formatting. So you will want to pass `--latexpand --keep-comments` to `git-latexdiff`.

The second issue is that `git-latexdiff` will make a temporary directory to store the diff files. You can tell `git-latexdiff` where to put these directories using the `--tmpdirprefix`, however the individual directories that are created each time you run `git-latexdiff` are named based upon the PID of the process. Therefore they are not easy to identify in order to run `texcount` on the generated diff files.

So based upon [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44626/31561) I decided to put the word count in the document itself on the first page. This way when `git-latexdiff` runs, it will call `texcount` automatically and put the word counts in the document. Then you can tell `git-latexdiff` to output that file somewhere (or just view it in the viewer) and see the word counts. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239805/31561) gives some good insight on making a template for `texcount`. I used this to make it output in a format that I could include in a `.tex` file so that it would look good in the pdf (adding new line characters, etc).

But that answer requires that output to be saved in a file and then input using the `\input` command. The problem is that the first time that `git-latex` runs, it will compile the document once, which will create the word count file, and then it will flatten the doc before sending it to `latexdiff`. When it flattens the document, it will put the contents of the word count file directly in the flattened document. This will have the total number of words correct, but it will not show any added or deleted words since the diff file has not been made by `latexdiff` yet. And it will not input the contents of the word count file after this, because `latexpand` has already flattened the document. Note that if you give `git-latexdiff` the `--no-flatten` option, it will indeed leave the individual files; however, it will **not** send all the files to `latexdiff` ([See this issue](https://gitlab.com/git-latexdiff/git-latexdiff/-/issues/66)). It will only diff the top level file. For a large document, this is useless since all the content is likely in separate `.tex` files.

I could not find a way to get `latexpand` to ignore this `input`. I also tried putting the `texcount` command directly in the document using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20566/31561), but `latexpand` still expands this and puts it in the document (I am using XeLaTeX). I could not find a way to get `latexpand` to ignore this command. (According to the [code](https://gitlab.com/latexpand/latexpand/-/blob/master/latexpand#L624), it also expands `\input` commands that are in `verbatim` environments).

To solve this, I used the `import` package, which provides a command `\import` that `\latexpand` does not expand. This way the word count file can be generated each time the document is compiled (importantly: on the final diff document from `latexdiff`.)

The last thing I did was to only do this when the document is in `draft` mode. If the document is being edited and changed and you want to see this changes, it makes sense that it only happens in draft mode. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49369/31561) for a list of things that draft mode changes. I added the command from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21235/31561) so that I could do stuff only in draft mode. I always want my pdf to have a TOC (since it is quite large), so I added [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66063/31561) as well so that `hyperref` will always generate a TOC.

So in the end I added this to my preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifdraft{\ifdim\overfullrule>\z@
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\makeatother

\hypersetup{final}
\ifdraft{\usepackage{import}}{}
```

And then at the beginning of my document I added:

```
%TC:newcounter add Added
%TC:newcounter del Deleted
%TC:macro \DIFadd [add]
%TC:macro \DIFdel [del]
%TC:ignore 
\immediate\write18{texcount -relaxed -sum -total -utf8 -opt=tc_template.cfg -merge \jobname.tex > 'WC.txt'}
\ifdraft{
{\LARGE \import{}{WC.txt}}
\clearpage}{}
```

For completeness, here is the content ot `tc_template.cfg`:

```
-template=
\Total Words: \textcolor{blue}{{sum}}\n\n
\Words in Text: {text}\n\n
\Words in Footnotes: {otherword}\n\n
\Words Added: \textcolor{green}{{add}}\n\n
\Words Deleted: \textcolor{red}{{del}}\n\n
\\rule{2.5in}{0.75pt}\n\n
\Words in Headers: {headerword}\n\n
\Num Headers: {header};  Floats: {float}\n\n
\Num Inline Math: {inline};  Display Math: {displaymath}\n\n
```

(I know that `otherword` in `texcount` can be things other than footnotes; but for my doc, it is nearly all footnotes. I also know that I could have put the `%TC`: macros in the config file. But I have lots of other `%TC:` comments in my document so that `texcount` ignores my preamble instead of parsing it, etc. So I just left them.)

The function that I call is:

```
git latexdiff --biber --xelatex --latexopt -shell-escape --main $1 --latexpand --keep-comments HEAD^1
```

I give it the name of the main `.tex` file. Since this solution uses `\write18`, remember that you will need to send the `-shell-escape` command to `xelatex`.

And that seems to work well. It puts the final word count and the added and deleted words in the final doc, which you can then peruse to see the differences in the last commit.

I might one day put this in CI in gitlab so that it generates this document automatically so that people can easily see what was changed, etc. That is for another day.